# Laravel 8 Error 404 appears but view already exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

Error 404|Not Found appears when i want to return a view.
According to the documentation I defined everything well but it does not works ToT. Please help!

Button:

```
<a class="btn btn-gradient-03 mr-1 mb-2" href="{{ route('seeds.import') }}">Import Database</a>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/seeds/import', 'App\Http\Controllers\web\v1\SeedController@import')->name('seeds.import');
```

Controller:

```
public function import()
{
    return view('seeds.import');
}
```

The view path is views\seeds\import.blade.php and the route appears on route:list.

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: Route should be: `Route::get('/seeds/import', [SeedController::class,'import'])->name('seeds.import');`

Comment: is the error message saying `View [seeds.import] not found.` ?

Comment: the `404` may be related to `Eloquent::findOrFail()`. are you doing queries in your service providers or controller's constructor ?

Comment: Have you tried running "php artisan view:clear"? Perhaps, there is an issue with the views cache.

Comment: No, only 404 error page. I will try php artisan view:clear and route:clear, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try running

Php artisan route:clear

Edit: im sorry I kind of made a mistake here

Try running

php artisan view:clear

Your views are most probably cached and therefore laravel reads from the cached views and not the actual view files

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment#optimizing-view-loading

Comment: But he says route appears in the route list right ?

Comment: Whether or not this is the correct answer, some more information here would be helpful for readers. Explaining why an answer will work is often just as useful as the specific change needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I try it but does not works